# Как удалить приложение с heroku?

Tags: heroku

Я только начал разбираться как работать с heroku и пока разбирался исчерпал лимит в 5 бесплатных приложений (на node.js). Где можно посмотреть url по которым доступны опубликованные мною приложения и их репозитории на GitHub и как можно удалить приложения?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Уничтожьте приложение:

```
heroku apps:destroy --app example
```

Создайте новое:

```
heroku create example
```

Нажмите на него:

```
git push heroku -u master
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вывести список приложений:

```
heroku apps
```

Уничтожить приложение:

```
heroku apps:destroy --app <Apps Name> --confirm <Apps Name>
```